# Saving leaflet maps in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have created an app where the user can modify a leaflet map and i would like to use this map in a pdf report. I have 
1. installed packages leaflet, webshot and htmlwidget
2. installed PhantomJS

below is a simplified version of the code

server.R:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(leaflet)
    library(htmlwidgets)
    library(webshot)

    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

      output$amap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner",
                     options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE,      reuseTiles=TRUE))
  })

  observe({
    leafletProxy("amap") %>%
    clearShapes() %>%
    addCircles(lng = c(22,-2), lat = c(42,65))
  })



  observeEvent(input$saveButton,{
    themap<- leafletProxy("amap")
    saveWidget(themap, file="temp.html", selfcontained = F) 
    webshot("temp.html", file = "Rplot.png",
          cliprect = "viewport")

  })
})
```

ui.R:

```
fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("amap", height="600px", width="600px"),
  br(),
  actionButton("saveButton", "Save")
  )
```

I get this error message:

Warning: Error in system.file: 'package' must be of length 1
Stack trace (innermost first):
    73: system.file
    72: readLines
    71: paste
    70: yaml.load
    69: yaml::yaml.load_file
    68: getDependency
    67: widget_dependencies
    66: htmltools::attachDependencies
    65: toHTML
    64: saveWidget
    63: observeEventHandler [C:\R files\test/server.R#24]
     1: shiny::runApp

when the save button is activated.
savewidget works fine when i define the save button like this:

```
  observeEvent(input$saveButton,{
    themap<-leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner",
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE, reuseTiles=TRUE))

    saveWidget(themap, file="temp.html", selfcontained = F) 
    webshot("temp.html", file = "Rplot.png",
          cliprect = "viewport")

  })
```

But i really want the changes that the user makes in the webshot. Can anyone help?

Comment: do you want the user to be able to save the file?  I think this would be better handled on the JavaScript side.  I'll try to work up an example for you.

Comment: well, my brilliant solution gets tangled up in cross-origin problems.  I'll try to think of another way to handle.

Answer (score 5):

This is not perfect, but here a solution using the library [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas).  Please be careful of attribution, license, and copyright.  Also, this **won't** work in RStudio Viewer, but there are ways to get it to work.

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)

lf <- leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(
    "Stamen.Toner",
    options = providerTileOptions(
      noWrap = TRUE,
      reuseTiles=TRUE
    )
  )


#  add the mapbox leaflet-image library
#   https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image
#lf$dependencies[[length(lf$dependencies)+1]] <- htmlDependency(
#  name = "leaflet-image",
#  version = "0.0.4",
#  src = c(href = "http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-image/v0.0.4/"),
#  script = "leaflet-image.js"
#)

lf$dependencies[[length(lf$dependencies)+1]] <- htmlDependency(
  name = "html2canvas",
  version = "0.5.0",
  src = c(href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/"),
  script = "html2canvas.min.js"
)



browsable(
  tagList(
    tags$button("snapshot",id="snap"),
    lf,
    tags$script(
'
document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var lf = document.querySelectorAll(".leaflet");
  html2canvas(lf, {
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      downloadLink.href = url;
      downloadLink.download = "map.png"

      document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
      downloadLink.click();
      document.body.removeChild(downloadLink); 
    }
  });
});
'      
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. I have not made it work inside my shiny app yet. I am not too strong in javascript.....will have to come back to it later this week. Thanks for the work so far